# Gradle could not resolve otto library

Tags: android, dependencies, repository, gradle, maven-central

I try to embed [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) library, [which exists at the Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cotto).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
}
```

But I get the exception:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'sample-project'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.squareup:otto:otto:1.3.4.
        Required by:
            :sample-project:unspecified
```

I tried to refresh dependencies(`gradle --refresh-dependencies`) but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell gradle where to find it.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Note that the existing `repositories { ... }` inside `buildscript { ... }` is only to configure the repositories for the build classpath itself, not your project, so put this new element just under `apply plugin ...`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're missing is `Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files`. I tested your code above and it worked just fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use Intellij(AndroidStudio) or Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I assumed you did since it looked much like an error message I've seen in IntelliJ, also trying to get Gradle dependenices to work properly. So if you're not using Android studio or Eclipse, I assume you're compiling etc from  the command line?